# zsh keeps removing the trailing slash from paths when I invoke a 3rd party text replacement tool

Tags: zsh

zsh keeps removing the trailing slash from paths when I invoke a 3rd party text replacement tool.

How can I stop it?

For example, if I type:
`cd /tmp/` and then invoke my text replacement app, zsh will reduce my command to `cd /tmp`. When the text replacement adds its text (e.g. "foo"), I now have `cd /tmpfoo` instead of `cd /tmp/foo`.

Is there an option to disable the feature that removes the trailing slashes?

Comment: Maybe the `MARK_DIRS` option will help? It's not clear what feature invoking your replacement tool invokes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on the [zshoptions](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshoptions) manpage:

> **AUTO_REMOVE_SLASH `<Default>`**
>
> When the last character resulting from a completion is a slash and the next character typed is a word delimiter, a slash, or a character that ends a command (such as a semicolon or an ampersand), remove the slash.

So to disable it:

`unsetopt AUTO_REMOVE_SLASH`

And then it will show up on setopt:

```
$ setopt | grep -i slash  
noautoremoveslash
```